# How do I assign one of the outputs of a module to the output of a different module?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, computer-architecture

```
module fullAdder(a, b, carryIn, carryOut, sum);
output carryOut, sum;
input a, b, carryIn;

wire w1, w2, w3, w4;


and G1(w1, a, carryIn);
and G2(w2, b, carryIn);
and G3(w3, a, b);
or G4(carryOut, w1, w2, w3);

xor G5(w4, a, b);
xor G6(sum, w4, carryIn);
endmodule
```

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module oneBitALU(result, carryOut, a, b, carryIn, opCode);
output reg result;
output reg carryOut;
input a, b, carryIn;
input [3:0] opCode;
wire w1, w2, w3, w4, sum;


fullAdder add(a, b, carryIn, carryOut, result);
fullAdder sub(a, ~b, 1, carryOut, result);

always@ (opCode, a, b)
begin
case(opCode)
    4'b0000: assign result = a&b;
    4'b0001: assign result = a|b;
    //4'b0010: 
    //4'b0110: 
    4'b1100: assign result = ~a&~b;
endcase
end
    

endmodule
```

I'm trying to assign the sum value of the `fullAdder` module to the result value of the `oneBitALU` module.  I'm pretty new to Verilog, so any help would be appreciated.  Lines 19 and 20 of the `oneBitALU` module are where I would assign the value.

Answer (score -1):

You can only have one source driving a given net, so having `result` being assigned in multiple places won't work (for synthesis at least). Furthermore the output a module cannot be connected directly to a `reg` type variable. Instead, to connect multiple things together in Verilog, you use `wire` (net data type).

For example

```
wire [3:0] addResult;

fullAdder add(..., addResult);

...

    4'b0010: result = addResult;
```

The same goes for `carryOut`. If you wrap all your cases in `begin-end` you can have multiple lines for each of the opCode cases, allowing you to assign both the `result` and `carryOut` variables during the case statement, again using intermediate `wire` data types to connect your `fullAdder` module outputs.

Furthermore, notice that inside the procedural `always` block, you don't need (and in pretty much all cases shouldn't) use the `assign` keyword. A simple `=` (blocking assignment) or `<=` (non blocking assignment) will do.

Comment: Might want to add that `@ (opCode, a, b)` should be changed to `@*` since `addResult` and other signals are being added to the sensitivity list.